# EFProf (Entity Framework Profiler) with IdeaBlade

Tags: performance, entity-framework, database-performance, query-performance, devforce

Have anybody used EFProf (http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/EFProf) with IdeaBlade?
I have problems with start working with that. There is the connection between apps (because I see name of the app in toolbar) but no queries are presented.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In an n-tier or Silverlight application make sure that you call the EFProf initialization on the server.  The application_start method in the global.asax is a good place for this.

Comment: I forgot to say that it is WPF Application and service with database is 'in cloud'. I Initialize profiler in App.xaml.cs, OnStartup event in my local application. 
Should I do it in service or is there any way to do it locally?

Comment: The EF access is all in the EntityServer in the cloud, not the WPF client, so you have to initialize EF Prof on the server too.